# How Does One Find the Binary Equivalent of a BigDecimal in Java?

Tags: java, binary, bigdecimal

There aren't any any existing answers for my question on Stock Exchange or anywhere else for that matter, at least not any that I could find yet. If this IS a duplicate, please include a link to the original answer.

Anyways, I'm programming an application in Java that converts a `BigDecimal` value into its binary value. I've successfully done this using a `BigInteger` applying the `toString(int radix)` method, and setting the `radix` to two. However, the `toString()` method for a `BigDecimal` does not accept a `radix` parameter.

I have considered parsing the BigDecimal into a `double` and using one of the Stock Exchange answers on getting a `double`'s binary form.

Please help :)

Answer (score 3):

Part of the issue is that this question is sort of nonsensical: many `BigDecimal`s have no representation as binary fractions; e.g. `0.1` is well known to have no exact binary representation.

If you just want to turn it into bits *somehow*, and you don't care the actual details of the representation, then call `BigDecimal.unscaledValue().toByteArray()` and combine that with `BigDecimal.scale()`.